# position: sticky not working in some device

Tags: html, css, sticky

I am trying to use position: sticky for tree structure where parent node of the tree is set to sticky. Here is the link to code file:

- The position sticky works file in all browsers in desktops.
- The tree crashes and parent node is not seen in laptops. Example: In chrome developer tools if I view the same tree in device toolbar->responsive mode, position sticky is not creating same problem and it crashes the list view.

Is there any work around for it?I have read a lot about position: sticky and think I am using it correctly. Since it works as expected in desktops all browsers and the problem is only in small devices or laptops.

Comment: Here is the link http://plnkr.co/edit/eyqTQ1BbjdIX87jGxDmD?p=preview

Comment: it is not supported by all browsers yet https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky but you can use absolute position with some top/left and width/height parameters.

Comment: ya. But it works in desktop and not in laptops or smaller screens. Is there any work around for it?

Comment: you could move the sticky one outside the scroll div.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
.col-container{
   position: relative;
}
.tree-resin .tree-root-item>.tree-heading{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 7;
    width: 89%;
}
.tree-root {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 50vh;
    padding-top: 53px;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/dn8aKQHaTAV4wMjRgd5g?p=preview